# Binding of blank value in @Html.DropDownListFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html.dropdownlistfor

I have a `ListItemCollection`, I'm passing it to `Html.DropDownListFor`, and I have a selected value. I want to show the selected value by default, but it is not working correctly.

```
ListItemCollection Abc = new ListItemCollection();
Abc.Add(new ListItem("", ""));
```

I have some values in **Test** List:

```
foreach (var abc in Test)
{
    Abc.Add(new ListItem(abc.Name, abc.Id.ToString()));
}

ViewBag.Test = Abc;
```

In the View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.MainReport.FlightType, new SelectList(ViewBag.Test, "Value", "Text"), new { id = "Test", @class = "form-control" })
```

The html generated for the DropDownList is:

```
<option value=""></option>
<option value="56">Cargo</option>
<option value="23">Ferry</option>
<option value="64">Other</option>
<option selected="selected" value="5">Passenger</option>
<option value="41">Training</option>
```

Now, as you see, **5** is selected by default, but it is still showing blank value, mean **first one**.

Comment: did you click browser back button ? Refresh your page and see what happens

Comment: did you check with other any browser?

Comment: Thanx all of you , issue resolved after 1 and half day , another piece of code is creating problem